# How to block the internet access but allow local host connection in a process

Tags: networking, process, network-interface, internet, namespace

I have a python program with 2 process running in docker:

1. my own server listening at 8080
2. an application listening at 8000

I am trying to block the internet access for the 2nd process. I was able to achieve this using `unshare` command.

However, my own server (1st process) needs to call the 2nd process. The command appears to block the local host connection as well.

When I call the 127.0.0.1:8000 from 1st process, I would get

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/upload (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffb48c59b20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))"

I tried `ip link set dev lo up` and I was able to ping the 127.0.0.1 but still got the same error when I try to call 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Docker is basically already using `unshare` to run containers, so why don't use two Docker containers, one for your server, and one for your application, together with a Docker internal network?

Comment: My server (1st process) is writing some files the application (2nd process) is reading. The 2nd process is an unmodified 3rd party application. So I guess using process is the only option

Comment: You could use a Docker volume to share files between both processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using user group

1. add a group "no-external-internet" and add your user to it

   ```
   sudo addgroup no-external-internet
   sudo adduser $USER no-external-internet
   ```
2. add iptables rules to accept the {HOST} outgoing traffic from {PORT} and reject all other outbound connections

   ```
   sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-external-internet -s {HOST} -p 
   tcp --sport {PORT} -j ACCEPT; 
   sudo iptables  -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-external-internet -j REJECT; 
   sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-external-internet -j REJECT;
   ```
3. run your child process with the user group:

   `sg no-external-internet "your command to run child process"`